# Bi Publisher empty page when using tables in PDF output

Tags: pdf, peoplesoft, bi-publisher, xml-publisher

RTF template defines a table that has a header row and and a single content row.

The content row has a Field that contains a for loop like this to populate the rows based on a XML data file:

```
<?for-each:row_MYDATA?>
...
...
<?end for-each?>
```

The issue happens when the table grows past the end of the page and overflows to the next page. The next page is as expected and contains the extra data just fine, but a page before the table beginning gets inserted and it's empty.

A text diagram of the issue if the table exceeds a single page:

```
| Empty page  |

| Table begins|

| Table cont. |
```

Expected:

```
| Table begins|

| Table cont. |
```

Comment: Do you have a keep together set on the table? This would be the expected behavior if you do.

Comment: @Kevin No, I do not have keep together set on any of the tables.

Comment: Well, the behavior you describe normally comes from the following scenario ... a keep condition is forcing the whole table to be kept together. This could be from the table itself, or possible keep-with-next on every row or even a higher level block or block-container with a keep on it. The formatter is trying to obey your rule to keep it all together and gets to the end of page, it gives up and a blank page results and the keep is broken allowing the table to break.

Comment: I had an SR with Oracle opened for over a year for them to fix this bug. They never did. “Working as designed” they said. I ended up arguing the page numbering was wrong and caused users to search for non existent pages that never printed. Is your first content row set to not break across pages?

Comment: FYI: SR 3-8065905828: Blank page at the beginning of a report